# how can I present table data in textboxes before and after updating process. asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net and I create textbox to allow user to insert his phone. he click save button to save his update. this is my code and it is working well:

```
conString = @"Data Source=admin\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection A= new SqlConnection(conString);
A.Open();
string updateProfile = "update userinfo set phone ='" + TextBox3.Text + "' where username ='" + userName + "' and password ='" + password + "'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(updateProfile, A);
 com.ExecuteNonQuery();
A.Close();
```

My question is:
when the user open the web page, the textbox apeares empty even if the main table contains old phone number.
how can I present old phone number in the textbox before the updating process? 
Then and after the updating process, textbox should present the new value
thank you

Comment: SQL Injection, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't indicate in your post if you ever read the data from the table, so assuming you don't, you can do a SELECT in the Page_Load event to get the user's data.

A bigger issue I see is that you are not using parameterized queries, so you are wide open for SQL Injection attacks.  Also, I would suggest using something other than `username` and `password` in your WHERE criteria - perhaps a UserID, which would be a unique identifier.

To load the data in the Page_Load event, the code might look something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("@"Data Source=admin\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True""))
{

    string sqlString = "SELECT phone FROM userinfo WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
    com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

    using (SqlReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            TextBox3.Text = reader[0].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of parameterized queries above (the "@username" and "@password" in the SQL string).  The parameters are filled in by the `AddWithValue` method.  I used a `SqlDataReader` as that is a relatively light-weight, forward-only mechanism to get the data from the result set.  Since it appears you're dealing with a user profile, you'd probably want to get all the data and load the information in the appropriate controls on the page.

Your code to update the phone number using a parameterized query would look something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("@"Data Source=admin\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True""))
{

    string sqlString = "UPDATE userinfo SET phone = @phone WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", TextBox3.Text);
    com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also note the use of the `using` blocks.  This will ensure that the connection object (and the data reader) will be properly disposed of, even if an exception occurs, as the objects will be disposed when the `using` block is exited.

Comment: I did the first code to read phone number. It is working well but now, other issue appear. the old phone number still in the database even after updating process. How can I make it ignore the old value after the update query??

Comment: If the old number is still in the database, that means the update command was not successful.  You don't want to ignore the old value in this case, you want to figure out why the update statement didn't work.  Where the username and password parameters correct?

Comment: the update statement was worked well before I add reading statement. So, I think that update statement is correct. But why it isn't working now? :(

Answer (score 0):

Simple, bind the values of text boxes to phone number at page load event.

Comment: This will work only if OP does a SELECT on the data in the table.

Comment: Right. He needs to fetch data from the DB at page load and then set the controls. What is OP by the way?

Comment: OP = Original Poster.  I.e., the person asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

On page_load fire a `select` query fetch the phone number and set to your textbox,

By this on pageload you will get phone no, later Update button click update it and on page load you will get updated value

Answer (score 0):

ohhhhhh

for it u need to use **select** query in load event which is fetch your phone number

then according to your requirement you can update value for it

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be also a possibility

```
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            cn.Open();

            cmd1.CommandText = "select *  from userinfo where "' where username ='" + userName + "' and password ='" + password + "'";
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Connection = cn;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
            da.Fill(ds, "userinfo ");
            if (ds.Tables["userinfo "].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables["userinfo "].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            }
```

Note: Here `ItemArray[1]` suggests the position of the item in DB,it may change in your instance.

Comment: Using a `DataSet` for something like has the potential to introduce a lot of unnecessary overhead, IMO.

Comment: Another possibility is to store the variable in session.